# Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've gone through other posts about this question but none of them don't seem to work for me.

Including change port number.
Stop World Wide Web Publishing Service. (i don't have it on my laptop)
i don't have skype or anything that could block port 80

Is there any other solutions, please?

Comment: what does the error log tell you? Have you made changes to either the `.htaccess` file or `http.conf` prior to the unexpected shutdown?

Comment: no all did was install xampp. this is the error log. http://pastebin.com/g7yrcc03

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using SSL, you should disable it to avoid these startup errors. I don't know XAMPP that much but it must have a config option to enable/disable the ssl mod.
Maybe this answer could help you to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117736

Comment: i tried this and still doesn't work still getting the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure to show us the full log, because I can't see the server stop error.

Comment: that error log i posted is all the error logs i have also this one that appears on the xampp control panel                                                    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
17:19:00  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:19:00  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:19:00  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:19:00  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:19:00  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
17:19:00  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: I'm no expert in XAMPP but did you try to launch it with administrator privileges?

Comment: it's fine now. i reinstalled xampp and it works. god knows how. but thank you for helping me